# Why does matplotlib imshow() display a transposed image?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, theano

I have an matrix of images created in matlab which i will be using as an input to a convolutional neural network i am coding in theano. I've imported the matrix using `numpy.loadtxt` and on inspection the matrix appears identical to the one created in matlab. When using `imshow()` in matlab i get the images displayed corrected, however, when using matplotlib `imshow()` the images are transposed. Does anyone know the cause of this?

Code for matlab:

```
    img = dlmread('kthImagesCheck.txt');
    imshow(reshape(img(:,1), [104,104]))
```

Code for matplotlib:

```
    img = numpy.loadtxt("kthImagesCheck", delimiter = ",")
    imshow(reshape(img[:,0],[104,104])
```

I would post the images but im new to stackoverflow and i don't have enough reputation yet.

Cheers,

Comment: You can post the links to images, a person with higher reputation will be able to insert them as images. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab and python has a different way to store arrays in memory. Matlab saves an array column-first, while python uses row-first method.
Consider, for example, a 2-by-2 matrix

```
M = [1, 2
     3, 4]
```

In memory, matlab save the matrix as `[1 3 2 4]` while python's order is `[1 2 3 4]`. This effect causes your image to be transposed.

Consider transposing the images in Matlab prior to saving them - this way the data is stored in memory in the same order as in python.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify shape of a numpy array with 2D array notation such as

```
1D_array = np.array(list)[:, None]
```

for vertical or

```
1D_array = np.array(list)[None, :]
```

for horizontal.
or you can use np.transpose()